# Using reflection to invoke a method from a library

Tags: c#, .net

How can I invoke a method from a dll? I'm trying to create a Menu which I can invoke from my static console application. I get the error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` error when I run this code.

```
public class Menu
{
    public string Title;
    public Type Program;
    public Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, MethodInfo>> Choices;

    public Menu(Type program, string title, string[,] choices)
    {
        Program = program;
        Title = title;
        Choices =
            new Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, MethodInfo>>();
        for (int i = 0; i < choices.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            Choices.Add(i,
                        new Tuple<string, MethodInfo>(choices[i, 0], program.GetMethod(choices[i, 1])));
        }
    }

    public void Create()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Title);
        for (int i = 0; i < Choices.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", i, Choices[i].Item1);
        int choice = ConsoleInput.GetNumber();
        while (choice < Choices.Count - 1)
            Choices[choice].Item2.Invoke(null, null);
    }
}
```

### Instantiation

The two methods that are invoked return void.

```
static readonly string[,] MainMenuChoices = new[,] {
    {"Invoke Testing", "InvokeTesting()"},
    {"Invoke Test","InvokeTest()"}
};

static readonly Menu MainMenu = new Menu(typeof(Program), "Menu Test", MainMenuChoices);
```

Comment: `GetMethod` expects the name of the method without any `()` parentheses -- and hence returns null, which eventually causes the NullReferenceException you're seeing.

Comment: Thank you very much! I overlooked that.

Comment: Unfortunately still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you tried using the debugger? Go through the code line by line, verifying that things are as you expect at each step. When something unexpected happens, you know that's where the bug is :-) Anyway, reading the code a little more carefully, I see that you're invoking the method without giving a "this" object (the first parameter, I think, which is `null` in your code). Unless the method is static, you should be passing an instance of the Program object (since the method belongs to Program). Also, that `while` loop is infinite, since `choice` never changes in it...

Comment: I figured out I needed the two void methods public.

Comment: Ah, that would do it :-) There's an overload of GetMethod which takes a second parameter of type BindingFlags, where you can specify `BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance` (for example) to get private members if you really want to.